# EZSQLException handling with message "SQL Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on xxx.xxx.x.xx(xxxxx)."

Tags: mysql, delphi, exception, zeos

I am working with MySQL server, Delphi and Zeoslib. Whenever I try to connect to my MySQL server running in another machine and it is shutoff on purpose, it throws an exception that it can't connect. I want to be able to suppress this exception or handle it properly. But my code doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
try
  WebSQLCon.Connect;
except
  on E: Exception do begin
    WebSQLCon.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

I can't see anything wrong with this code. So, why is it not handling the exception instead of popping up the message?

UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: The exception handling looks dubious at best. Do you really mean to swallow all exceptions like that. And if `Connect` raises an exception, why would you need to call `Disconnect`.

Comment: Perhaps that's it. Perhaps the exception is raised in your call to `Disconnect`? Note that we are compelled to guess as to what `WebSQLCon` is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan webSQLCon is TZConnection. I just debugged the code and the exception is raised at `WebSQLCon.Connect`. When you okay the message, it then jumps to `WebSQLCon.Disconnect` and no exceptions raised.

Comment: What displays the error message? Is it the debugger? Is the error dialog displayed when you execute outside the debugger? Also, what do you expect to happen after you've swallowed this exception? Are you hoping that somehow, the rest of your code that relies on the connection existing, is not going to object to the fact that it does not. What do you know about exception handling? Do you know that best practice is that you don't handle exceptions and let them float up the call stack until they are caught by something that does know how to handle them?

Comment: I would also like to point you to my original comment. *Do you really mean to swallow all exceptions like that? And if Connect raises an exception, why would you need to call `Disconnect`?*

Comment: I don't see any reason in your code why it would raise an exception. However, as David points out, you do need to understand how to handle exceptions. My guess would be your server is not accessible, which is the most plausible cause.

Comment: @JerryDodge You've missed the point. The question is not about why the exception is raised, but rather about what to do when it is raised. The asker wants the program to behave sensibly when the connection cannot be made.

Comment: @JerryDodge Yes, I intentionally have my server shut off. I simply want the program to connect if not just continue without raising any exception.

Comment: There is usually (actually very often, if you are not working explicitly with the connection object) no need to explicitly connect to the server. Dataset components can do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the debugger breaking on the exception. The dialog you have presented in your screenshot is not displayed by the program. Rather the debugger displayed it. You can click on the *Continue* button to proceed.

If you wish to disable this dialog you can do so from the debugger area of the IDE options. These settings can be found under *Tools | Options | Debugger Options | Language Exceptions*. There you can uncheck *Notify on language exceptions* to suppress this dialog. However, that's not generally something to be recommended. You might perhaps suppress this exception class by adding to the list of exceptions that are ignored. However, now that you know what causes this you may prefer just to press the *Continue* button.

Note that as discussed in the comments, it seems very likely that your swallow all exception handler code is the wrong way to deal with the issue of `Connect` failing.

Comment: :) Yep.... I just ran my program without debugging and it is working just as you described. Thanks.